# Unwrapping optional value (returned by data.withUnsafeBytes(_:)) sometimes does not work with guard let

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have issue with guard let statement, which behaves strange. Whole code is below. Else block of statement `guard let data = readData, let size = sizeOfData else ...` in method `readActivity(subdata: Data)` is wrongly executed even thoug `readData` and `sizeOfData` are not `nil`.

### Code

```
import Foundation

enum ActivityDataReaderError: Error {
    case activityIsReadingOtherCentral
    case bluetooth(Error?)
    case staleData
}

protocol ActivityDataReaderDelegate: class {
    func didReadActivity(data: Data)
    func didFailToReadActivity(error: ActivityDataReaderError)
}

final class ActivityDataReader {
    private var sizeOfData: Int?
    private var isOtherDeviceReading: Bool {
        // 0xFFFF
        return sizeOfData == 65535
    }
    private var readData: Data?

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return sizeOfData == nil
    }

    weak var delegate: ActivityDataReaderDelegate?

    static func timestampValue(_ timestamp: UInt32) -> Data {
        var value = timestamp
        return Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &value, count: 1))
    }

    func reset() {
        readData = nil
        sizeOfData = nil
        NSLog("reset() -- \(Thread.current)")
    }

    func readActivity(data: Data?, error: Error? = nil) {
        guard let data = data else {
            delegate?.didFailToReadActivity(error: .bluetooth(error))
            return
        }
        let isFirstChunk = readData == nil
        if isFirstChunk {
            let sizeData = data.subdata(in: 0..<2)
            sizeOfData = sizeData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
            guard !isOtherDeviceReading else {
                delegate?.didFailToReadActivity(error: .activityIsReadingOtherCentral)
                return
            }
            NSLog(String("readActivity() Size of data: \(String(describing: sizeOfData))"))
            let subdata = data.subdata(in: 2..<data.count)
            readActivity(subdata: subdata)
        } else {
            readActivity(subdata: data)
        }
    }

    private func readActivity(subdata: Data) {
        if let lastReadData = readData {
            readData = lastReadData + subdata
        } else {
            readData = subdata
        }
        guard let data = readData, let size = sizeOfData else {
            NSLog("WTF? data:\(String(describing: readData)), "
                + "sizeOfData: \(String(describing: sizeOfData)), "
                + "thread: \(Thread.current)")
            assertionFailure("WTF")
            return
        }
        NSLog("subdata: \(String(describing: subdata)), "
            + "totalReadBytes: \(data.count), "
            + "size: \(size)")
        if data.count == size {
            delegate?.didReadActivity(data: data)
            reset()
        }
    }
}
```

### Test

Test which sometimes passes and sometimes crashes because of `assertionFailure("WTF")`.

```
class ActivityDataServiceReaderTests: XCTestCase {
    var service: ActivityDataReader?

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        service = ActivityDataReader()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        service = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testBufferIsNotEmpty() {
        NSLog("testBufferIsNotEmpty thread: \(Thread.current)")
        guard let service = service else { fatalError() }
        let firstDataBytes = [UInt8.min]
        let data1 = Data(bytes: [7, 0] + firstDataBytes)
        service.readActivity(data: data1)
        XCTAssertFalse(service.isEmpty)

        service.reset()
        XCTAssertTrue(service.isEmpty)
    }
}
```

### Log of console in case of crash

```
2018-10-25 14:53:30.033573+0200 GuardBug[84042:11188210] WTF? data:Optional(1 bytes), sizeOfData: Optional(7), thread: <NSThread: 0x600003399d00>{number = 1, name = main}
```

### Environment

- Xcode10
- swift 4.1 with legacy build system
- swift 4.2

In my opinion, there is no possible way to execute code in else block in guard let else block of method `readActivity(subdata: Data)`. Everything is running on main thread. Am I misssing something? How is possible sometimes test passes and sometimes crasshes?

Thank you for any help.

### Edit:

More narrow problem of guard let + data.withUnsafeBytes:

```
func testGuardLet() {
    let data = Data(bytes: [7, 0, UInt8.min])
    let sizeData = data.subdata(in: 0 ..< 2)
    let size: Int? = sizeData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
    guard let unwrappedSize = size else {
        NSLog("failure: \(size)")
        XCTFail()
        return
    }
    NSLog("success: \(unwrappedSize)")
}
```

Log:

```
2018-10-25 16:32:19.497540+0200 GuardBug[90576:11351167] failure: Optional(7)
```

Comment: try to optional wrapping each value separately, and check log of each when crash happens

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include only _relevant_ code in your question. Don't just dump whole classes and make people read through code that has nothing to do with what you're asking. Please read [mcve] and [edit] your question to show the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The only thing that I can see here that could potentially cause something like what you're describing would appear to be a race condition with sizeOfBytes. When you assign to it in `readActivity(data:error:)`, you're using a closure. I would recommend putting a log statement in `didSet` for sizeOfBytes and seeing if this is in fact the cause.

Comment: @jlowe didSet is called on main thread so this is not caused by race condition.

Comment: @Tobi @jlowe when I try to unwrap each value separately, problem is with `sizeOfData`. This causes of execution `else` block but in log I can see its value is not `nil`

Comment: The property `sizeOfData` has very strange behavior. In method readActivity(data: Data?, error: Error?) has the property value `Optional(7)` before the method `readActivity(subdata: subdata)` is called. In method readActivity(subdata: Data) before `guard let` statement has `nil` and in else block of `guard let` has value `Optional(7)` again.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying. I'm suggesting to put the `didSet` to log when the value of `sizeOfData` changes because it's being set via a closure in the `sizeData.withUnsafeBytes` call. This would show you when the value is actually being set and you can verify the behavior is as you expect.

Comment: @jlowe `didSet` of property `sizeOfData` is called before `readActivity(subdata: Data)`

Comment: If I'm interpreting [this Swift forum post](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-data-withunsafebytes-in-a-well-defined-manner/12811) correctly the behavior of returning the `pointee` from `Data.withUsafeBytes` is not entirely well defined. It seems like it's not undefined behavior with the current implementation but neither does it seem to be well defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help at: https://forums.swift.org/t/unwrapping-value-with-guard-let-sometimes-does-not-work-with-result-from-data-withunsafebytes-0-pointee/17357 problem was with the line:

```
let size: Int? = sizeData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
```

Where read data was downcasted to Optional Int (8 bytes long) but sizeData it self was just 2 bytes long. I have no idea how is possible it sometimes worked but solution -- which seems to work properly -- is to use method `withUnsafeBytes` in fallowing way:

```
let size = sizeData.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) in pointer.pointee }
```

Returned value is not optional and has the proper type UInt16 (2 bytes long).

Answer (score 0):

If you check [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780450-withunsafebytes), there is a warning:

> Warning The byte pointer argument should not be stored and used
>   outside of the lifetime of the call to the closure.

Seems like You should deal with the size inside the closure body

```
func testGuardLet() {
        let data = Data(bytes: [7, 0, UInt8.min])
        var sizeData = data.subdata(in: 0 ..< 2)
        withUnsafeBytes(of: &sizeData) { bytes in
            print(bytes.count)
            for byte in bytes {
                print(byte)
            }
        }

        let bytes = withUnsafeBytes(of: &sizeData) { bytes in
            return bytes // BUGS ☠️☠️☠️
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try it few times with `Clean Build Folder` even with print. It will fail sometimes too. (I am trying it with XCTest)

Comment: Missed one thing. Updating my answer.

Comment: Problem is not with `variable declared in 'guard' condition is not usable in its body`. In example code is not anywhere used unwrapped value inside else block. Issue is that value assigned by `sizeData.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }` is for `guard let` nil, but inside else block has value `7`.

Comment: @MichalRaška, sorry for misleading in the first answer. Answered too fast. Please, check an update.

Comment: If I understant it well, you suggest exactly that, what documentation says shouldn't be done.

Comment: @MichalRaška, no, i think you didn't understand me. Updated code sample once again.

Comment: You were trying to return pointer fom `withUnsafeBytes`. I suggest you to use it inside the closure.